# How to save the state of a Live CD into a .iso?

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, cd-image

I would like to create an Ubuntu Flavor with custom settings and packages.

I think a simple way of doing it would be to just boot Ubuntu from an USB, modify settings un/install packages and save the state of the OS into a .iso that can later be written into a drive and booted with my modifications kept.

But how do I save the state of a Live CD into a file?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Persistent Storage:

[LiveUsbPendrivePersistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)